# SQL Regenerate Guid PK

Tags: sql-server, guid

Hello I have a scenario where I have multiple SQL databases, and a tool on a central database which connects to each user table on each database and builds a dataset.

The issue happens when say a user from one database is migrated to another. When the tool runs it encounters an issue because the user_id is a guid pk, and since users have been migrated across databases the dataset will end up having duplicate private keys in the final dataset.

> My question,  if I want to regenerate the user id guid for some user,
>   I of course have to also update all of the connecting foreign keys. Is
>   there a command in MS SQL to regenerate the GUID and also do so for
>   all connecting relationships?

Comment: Nothing automatic that I'm aware of. How many tables containing the FK are there? It should straightforward to create a SP to do this, or build it into your migration process. Do you need to remember the original GUID at all? If you overwrite it you'll never be able to deduplicate these afterwards if that is required.

Answer (score 0):

`ON UPDATE CASCADE` is what you want, but you need to define it in the foreign key relationship ahead of time.

```
CREATE TABLE User (UserID UNIQUEIDENTIFIER, UserName varchar(30), ... )

CREATE TABLE UserData (DataID UNIQUEIDENTIFIER, UserID UNIQUEIDENTIIFER, ...)

ALTER TABLE UserData
    ADD CONSTRAINT FK_UserData_UserID (UserID) REFERENCES User(UserID)
        ON UPDATE CASCADE;
```

Comment: oh great, this may be what I need, thanks. I dont think it has been defined in the relationship a head of time, but I am sure I could modify it to add that property. Thanks, I will let you know how it goes.